# Excel add-in keeps on getting disabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I installed the TTS Turbo Macros 5 (an .xla, so an Excel Add-in not a COM add-in). It's housed in the AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\ folder.

Every time I close Excel (365) fully and then reopen it, the macro no longer works (the hotkeys are gone, the menu is gone). However, it's still "Active" in the Add-ins menu. When I go to Manage -> Excel Add-ins and macros in (3disable it and then enable it, it comes back. Any sense of why this is? I know this happens with personal workbooks but have not seen this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the two options below are not selected in the Trust Center- Add ins.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the location where it's housed in the "Trusted Locations" within the Trust Center section. You won't have to reenable it every time you start the program after that. This fixed the problem for me permanently ;)